# how to move various f-curves with modifier in the timeline?

Tags: modifiers

I have pack of animated objects, each one animated with a built in function modifier.
If I want to change the location of the animation for one object in the timeline I have to change the phase offset value in the modifier.

I try to find how to do it for all my animated objects in the same time.
Not to put the same offset value to all the modifier but to add a value to all their values(that are not the same values for each one)

Thank you.

Comment: i tried using a custom property to do that but it isn't working with f-curve modifiers. actually a lot of stuff (like drivers and keyframes) don't work with them, which is a pain...